# CodeIgniter, trouble loading a custom config in a library class

Tags: php, codeigniter, config, codeigniter-3

I am trying to load a custom config file within a library class. I am running into issues where the config values are returning null.

config file: 'couriers.php'

```
$config['ups'] = 'some keys';
```

library file: '/library/Track/Ups.php'

```
class Ups {

    public $ci;

    public function __contruct() {

        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->ci->config->load('couriers');
    }

    public function GetUPSKey() {

       return config_item('ups');

    }
}
```

I am getting a NULL response.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing your code. I found only one issue that is simply typo mistake for `constructor`. You miss spelled it. So the constructor never get called. Change it and check. Other things are fine

```
public function __construct() {

        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->ci->config->load('couriers');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Class */

```
class Ups {

    protected $ci;
    protected $config;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->ci =& get_instance();

        // Loads a config file named couriers.php and assigns it to an index named "couriers"
        $this->ci->config->load('couriers', TRUE);

        // Retrieve a config item named ups contained within the couriers array
        $this->config = $this->ci->config->item('ups', 'couriers');
    }

    public function GetUPSKey() {

       return $this->config['key'];

    }
}
```

/* Config (couriers.php) */

```
$config['ups'] = array(
    'key' => 'thisismykey',
    'setting2' => 'etc'
);

// Additional Couriers etc
$config['dhl'] = array(
    'key' => 'thisismykey',
    'setting2' => 'etc'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load configuration and point it to an object and use that while return:

```
class Ups {

    public $ci;

    public function __contruct() {

        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->couriers_config = $this->ci->config->load('couriers');
    }

    public function GetUPSKey() {

       return $this->couriers_config['ups'];

    }
}
```